# "The volume filesystem root has only..."

Tags: disk-usage, disk-management

I am having this problem in ubuntu 12.04, but I fin strange that when I go to /tmp it wont allow me to delete some files, with message "Operation not permitted" or "this file could not be handled because you dont have permissions to read it".

It is only a PC and I have the root password.

I was trying to get at least 2000 MB of free space on the root file system to upgrade to 12.10 and see if that resolved the problem. Currently free space on root file system is 190 MB.

This is my output:

```
root@jcsalazar-Vostro-3550:~# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6        7688360 7112824    184984  98% /
udev             2009288       4   2009284   1% /dev
tmpfs             806636    1024    805612   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             2016584    5316   2011268   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda5         472036  255920    191745  58% /boot
/dev/sda7       30758848 7085480  22110900  25% /home
root@jcsalazar-Vostro-3550:~# sudo parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MK3261GS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   primary   fat16
 2      106MB   15.8GB  15.7GB  primary   ntfs            boot
 3      15.8GB  278GB   262GB   primary   ntfs
 4      278GB   320GB   41.9GB  extended
 5      278GB   279GB   499MB   logical   ext4
 6      279GB   287GB   7999MB  logical   ext4
 7      287GB   319GB   32.0GB  logical   ext4
 8      319GB   320GB   1443MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

I apprecciate any new ideas that can help me.
Thnx
Carlos

Answer (score 0):

Increase root / from 7GB by a few more GB from /home.

Create an installation LiveCD or USB and load it as “Try Ubuntu” to run outside of your target OS, to resize and move the partitions, using the application GParted. Please read and learn about this activity as it is risky and tricky to move the partitions.